# list of all external devices ever connected to my laptop?

Tags: security, modem

1. where can i find the list of all external devices(pen drives,other laptop,hdd etc) ever connected to my laptop?
2. where in windows can i find the modem logs nd all modem connectivity and Usage activity logs?
   os: win7\xp.

Comment: You kinda posted two different questions under one ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. To view USB History I would suggest to use USBDeview tool for this:
   http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html

   If you however want technical details on how and where windows stores such data, you can have a look at http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/USB_History_Viewing for detailed information.

   > When a USB removable storage device is connected to a Windows system for the first time, the Plug and Play (PnP) Manager receives the event notification, queries the device descriptor for the appropriate information to develop a device class identifier (device class ID) and attempts to locate the appropriate driver for that device.
   >   Looking for and installing the correct driver for the device is recorded in the setupapi.log file.
2. For modem logs I would look for `C:\Windows\System32\ModemLog_Model.txt` file (note you need to replace `_Model` with your Modem's model). Not sure if this will still work on Windows 7.